# When does a pushout of monics induces a monic arrow?

Tags: category-theory

There are lots of arguments in the homotopy theory of simplicial sets (I refer bascially to the first chapter of Goerss-Jardine) which exploit the fact that in certain cases the map induced in a pushout diagram made of monic arrows by two monic arrows is again monic.

The basic claim

> **BC**: the map induced in a pushout diagram made of monic arrows by two monic arrows is again monic.

is false in general, even in "well-behaved" categories: consider the pushout diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\varnothing &\to & 1 \\
\downarrow &&\downarrow\\
1 &\to &2
\end{array}
$$
and the arrows $1\to 1$ on both sides.

So my question: I am looking either for conditions which ensure that **BC** is true or for a method to verify that a given arrow in a pushout diagram is/can't be a monic. I am in particular interested in the arrow naturally induced by $(K\times X)\coprod_{K\times Y}(L\times Y)\to L\times K$, by two monics $K\subset L, Y\subset X$. The product functor preserves monics, pushout of monics in a topos is monic, hence I'm left with a diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
K\times Y &\to& L\times Y \\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
K\times X&\to&L\times X
\end{array}
$$
which must factor through the pushout. Is this factorization made of monics?

Comment: But **BC** (in its full generality) is false in $\mathbf{sSet}$ as you have already observed! The pushout–product map you are interested in is a monomorphism because this particular pushout computes the union of subobjects. This is true in any elementary topos.

Comment: Ah, now I see the light: $(L\times Y)\cap (K\times X) = K\times Y$, as in diagram 2. here http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject#LimitsAndColimits

So simple that I feel ashamed.